# How to Sort Posts Alphabetically in Jekyll

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

I am trying to sort my posts in my Categories page alphabetically instead of by date. With that, I am trying to assign a new variable `sorted_posts`,but I get errors in regards to an `endfor`

```
--- 
layout: page
--- 
{% unless page.content == '' %}
{{ content }} 
{% endunless %} 
<ul class="posts-list">
   {% assign category = page.category | default: page.title %}
   {% assign sorted_posts = site.categories[category] | sort: post.title}
   {% for post in site.categories[category] %}
      <li>
        <h3>
          <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ post.url }}">
            {{ post.title }}
            <!-- <small>{{ post.date | date_to_string }}</small> -->
          </a>
        </h3>
      </li>   {% endfor %} </ul>
```

where the error is

```
Error: Liquid syntax error (line 16): Unknown tag 'endfor'
Error: Run jekyll build --trace for more information.
```

Thank you very much! =]

Comment: You're missing an ending `%` on your second `assign` line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's because you are missing an `%` at line 6. Try changing it for:

```
{% assign sorted_posts = site.categories[category] | sort: post.title %}
```

Your for syntax seems right.